# After fixing NetCDF Extent Then Saving using R cannot open in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, r, netcdf

I have some NetCDF files that aren't displaying correcly in ArcMap 10.7 (or when plotted in R...). I found some help fixing the extent [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271779/r-netcdf-to-raster). Here is what I see for the extent:

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(gdalUtils)

filename <- "./netcdf_test/comp20180702.120000.nc"

tpw_raster <- brick(filename, varname="tpwGrid")
```

Result:

```
> tpw_raster <- brick(filename, varname="tpwGrid")
[1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named lon BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point"
[1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named lat BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point"
```

```
tpw_raster; class(tpw_raster)
```

Result:

```
> tpw_raster; class(tpw_raster)
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 721, 1440, 1038240, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1, 1.998611  (x, y)
extent     : 0.5, 1440.5, 0.0006944444, 1440.999  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : comp20180702.120000.nc 
names      : layer 
varname    : tpwGrid 

[1] "RasterBrick"
attr(,"package")
[1] "raster"
```

Here I check the extent info, then fix the extent, and try to write the file:

```
polnc <- nc_open(filename)

#Get extent info
ncvar_get(polnc, "lonArr")
ncvar_get(polnc, "latArr")

extent(tpw_raster) <- c(-180, 179.75, -90, 90)

#plot(tpw_raster)

writeRaster(tpw_raster, "./netcdf_test/test01.nc", format="CDF", varname="tpw", xname="lon", yname="lat", overwrite=TRUE)
#Creates a .nc file, but it is does not open in ArcGIS: "ERROR 000237 One or more dimensions are invald"

#writeGDAL(tpw_raster, "./netcdf_test/test01.adf",drivername = "AIG", type = "Float32")
#Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
#  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘gridded’ for signature ‘"RasterBrick"’
```

When I use `writeRaster` a file is produced but I get the stated error when I try to open it in ArcGIS. I first tried `writeGDAL` because ultimately I want it to be in GRID format but I get an error for that also. Here's what I see when I look at in in R (it seems to plot fine):

```
filename2 <- "./netcdf_test/test01.nc"

tpw_out <- brick(filename2, varname="tpw")
tpw_out; class(tpw_out)
```

Result:

```
> tpw_raster; class(tpw_raster)
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 721, 1440, 1038240, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.2498264, 0.2496533  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 179.75, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : comp20180702.120000.nc 
names      : layer 
varname    : tpwGrid 

[1] "RasterBrick"
attr(,"package")
[1] "raster"
> filename2 <- "./netcdf_test/test01.nc"
> tpw_out <- brick(filename2, varname="tpw")
> tpw_out; class(tpw_out)
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 721, 1440, 1038240, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.2498264, 0.2496533  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 179.75, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : test01.nc 
names      :       X1 
min values :   0.0625 
max values : 106.9375 
z (unknown): 1 
varname    : tpw 

[1] "RasterBrick"
attr(,"package")
[1] "raster"
```

Could ArcMap not liking it have something to do with the "z (unknown)?"

I don't have or need a time dimension or any other z dimension.

Comment: Historically, ESRI software does not care for rasters with different  x,y cell dimensions. Perhaps, try setting the cell resolution to the same value eg., `res(x) <- c(0.2498264, 0.2498264)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried `res(tpw_raster) <- c(0.2498264, 0.2498264)` before `extent(tpw_raster) <- c(-180, 179.75, -90, 90)` and I get `Warning message:
In .local(x, filename, ...) : all cell values are NA`. When I switch the order I get `Warning message:
In .couldBeLonLat(x, warnings = warnings) :
  raster has a longitude/latitude CRS, but coordinates do not match that`. Either way I still get the same error in ArcGIS.

Comment: Any help on this? I think the issue I'm having here has to do with the z (unknown): 1 statement. When I try to add it in ArcGIS 'z' shows up as an option for for x dimension and y dimension. I have tried looking for ArcGIS and/or Python solutions to this and I've come up blank on both. I don't really care what solution to use, but I ultimately need to get these NetCDFs into GRID files with the right extent.